# I need some help on the steps to do eager evaluation on a Lambda calculus expression?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm confused on how to trace the eager evaluation steps of the this Lambda Calculus expression. I'm not sure what the steps are.

(λu.(u λg.λh.h) ((λx.λy.λf.((f x) y) a) b))

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the term you have given is already in normal form and cannot be reduced, since all applications use the variables associated in lambda abstractions in the first place.
If you have any difficulties with reducing terms, I advise you to use some online tool. For example: [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmk35/lambda_calculus/lambda_calculus.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ermk35/lambda_calculus/lambda_calculus.html)